# SQLite search for string that starts with xyz

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am currently programming a SQLite database for a recipe app.  I want to search based on recipe name (String name) . When I search for "Fast food" everything works fine. However, if I search only for "Fast", no entries are returned. I know that the mistake is in this line: " LIKE ? " . Unfortunately I don't know what the correct term is.
I hope you can help me.
Thanks

```
public List<Recipe> selectAllByName(String name) {
        List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Cursor cursor = db.query(Config.TABLE_NAME,
                new String[]{Config.KEY_ID, Config.KEY_NAME, Config.KEY_CATEGORY, Config.KEY_IMAGE_PATH, Config.KEY_TIME, Config.KEY_SERVICE,},
                Config.KEY_NAME + " LIKE ? ", new String[]{name}, null, null, null)) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Recipe recipe = new Recipe(
                            cursor.getLong(0),
                            cursor.getString(1),
                            cursor.getString(2),
                            cursor.getString(3),
                            cursor.getString(4),
                            cursor.getString(5));
                    recipe.setIngredients(ingredientDAO.selectAllByRecipeId(recipe.getId()));
                    recipe.setDirections(directionDAO.selectAllByRecipeId(recipe.getId()));
                    recipes.add(recipe);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        return recipes;
    }
```

Comment: In SQL's `LIKE`, `%` is the wildcard to match multiple characters, and `_` is the wild card to match single characters.  So, `LIKE '%Smith%'` makes sense, but `LIKE 'Smith'` is the same as `= 'Smith'` : [SQLite Docs on LIKE](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_and_match_operators)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. Could you tell me what I have to change in my case to make it work?

Comment: Either pass the parameter to your function as `Fast%` rather than `Fast`, or append the `%` character to the string as part of your function.  *(Assuming you only want 'starts with'.  If you want 'contains' then the string `name` should have a `%` character at both the start and at the end.)*